# How can I cache files into sub folders to reduce the number of inodes in the cache folder?

Tags: php, caching

My site is caching all the files correctly in the specified folders, however, there are too many files being stored in these folders.  I was thinking of splitting the cache folder up into sub directories that contain the first letter of the file name and then possibly breaking it down further from there.

As you can see below, a compressed version is saved in a 'gz' folder and a regular cache is stored in a 'html2' folder.

Code:

```
if ( $cache ) {
#header("Content-Type: text/html");
// get the buffer
$buffer = ob_get_contents();
#$length = ob_get_length();
#header('Content-Length: '.$length);
// end output buffering, the buffer content
// is sent to the client
ob_end_flush();

// now we create the cache file
if (!file_exists($pathName)) {
    mkdir($pathName, 0755, true);
}
if (!file_exists(str_replace('/html/html2/', '/html/gz/', $pathName))) {
    mkdir(str_replace('/html/html2/', '/html/gz/', $pathName), 0755, true);
}
$compressed = preg_replace('%<!--(.|\s)*?-->%', '', $buffer);
$compressed = sanitize_output($compressed);
$encoded = gzencode($compressed, 9);
file_put_contents($file, $compressed);
file_put_contents(str_replace('/html/html2/', '/html/gz/', str_replace('.html', '.gz', $file)), $encoded);

}
```

Based on the above code, here is the path of the current cache files:

```
/html2/New-York-Hotels.html

/gz/New-York-Hotels.gz
```

Ideally, I would like the cached file locations to look like this:

```
/html2/N/New-York-Hotels.html

/gz/N/New-York-Hotels.gz
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: A little off topic, but why are you storing both a compressed *and* an uncompressed version? Wouldn't it be better to store one type (the most commonly used) and convert to the other on demand? Gzip is not exactly a particularly time or resource consuming process, and if the data is HTML it's not likely to be very big.

Comment: Dave, this site was built by someone that doesn't work for us anymore and I am not exactly sure if there is a reason both types are being cached.  All I know is that I don't want to do anything to jeopardize our traffic.  Thanks for your concern ;-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code (**FIXED**):

```
if ($cache) {

  // Get the buffer into a string
  // I do it this way to save memory - no point in keeping 2 copies of the data
  $buffer = ob_get_clean();

  // Send buffer content to the client
  // header("Content-Type: text/html");
  // header('Content-Length: '.strlen($buffer));
  echo $buffer;
  flush();

  // Get the paths into sensibly named variables
  $fileBase = basename($file); // The name of the HTML file
  $htmlPath = rtrim($pathName, '/').'/'.strtoupper($fileBase[0]).'/'; // The directory the HTML file is stored in
  $gzPath = str_replace('/html/html2/', '/html/gz/', $htmlPath); // The directory the gzipped file is stored in
  $htmlFile = $htmlPath.$fileBase; // The full path of the HTML file
  $gzFile = $gzPath.str_replace('.html', '.gz', $fileBase); // The full path of the gzipped file

  // Make sure the paths exist
  if (!is_dir($htmlPath)) {
    mkdir($htmlPath, 0755, true);
  }
  if (!is_dir($gzPath)) {
    mkdir($gzPath, 0755, true);
  }

  // Strip comments out of the file and sanitize_output() (whatever than does)
  // $compressed is a silly name for a variable when we are also zipping the data
  $html = sanitize_output(preg_replace('%<!--(.|\s)*?-->%', '', $buffer));

  // Save the files
  file_put_contents($htmlFile, $html);
  file_put_contents($gzFile, gzencode($html, 9));

}
```

There are several unchecked potential errors here that should be handled, for example what happens if `mkdir()` fails, and what happens if `file_put_contents()` fails?

Comment: Excellent, works like a charm. I will have to address the mentioned potential errors. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I really wish Stack Overflow offered a feature where you could buy someone a beer for helping you out!

Comment: @NotJay No worries, StackOverflow is beer for the soul... :-D